# Terraform user_data output split on newlines

Tags: terraform

I'm outputting userdata successfully, but it comes out with embedded newlines. What would be the best or easiest way to format this in a readable fashion, rather than a single line with escaped newlines?

This is my userdata.tf:

```
data "template_file" "userdata" {
  count    = var.instance-count
  template = file("${path.module}/userdata.sh")

  vars = { ...
```

The template is, of course, just a file with vars in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# wait for internet
```

This is my output resource.

```
output "userdata" {
  value = data.template_file.userdata[*].rendered
}
```

```
Outputs come out with newlines on the terminal:

master_userdata = [
  "#!/bin/bash\n\n# wait for...
```

This would better be readable like:

```
Outputs:

master_userdata = [
  "#!/bin/bash

# wait for...
```

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code as a [mcve] so that people can see exactly what you've tried so far please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your intention, you do want to define some Terraform output variable with newlines in its value. So, if you organize your configuration as follows (note the "broken" indentation — Terraform processes such multiline entries as is):

```
output "master_userdata" {
  value = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
# wait for...
EOF
}
```

you'll probably achieve your goal. Have a good one!

Comment: I updated my question to hopefully be more clear. I've already inserted userdata but while developing it, I'd like to to me more human-readable.

Or maybe I don't understand your answer! Looks like you are explicitly typing a data block into the output value.